# How to add class attributes to Bootstrap tree view items?

Tags: jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap, treeview

I am trying to create a Bootstrap Tree View and have the items divided in categories, each category having a separate context menu.
For example I can have "Flowers" and "Cars" as tree items, and when user right clicks on Flowers there can be a menu of ("Color","Smell") and for Cars another menu of ("Engine power", "Price").

I am not very good at jQuery, but I think I need to associate "classes" to categories nodes (using html "class" tag or something) and then associate a listener for right click to those classes, and depending on class name, show a different menu  content in specific mouse coordinates.

Question is :
Is my approach right ? and if so, how can I specify class name for Boostrap Tree nodes when populating the tree using  JSON data ?

Sorry for long text, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just fyi: *Right clicking* is usually reserved for context menus, not navigation.

And with regard to Bootstrap:

- A "treeview", in Bootstrap terms, is simply a vertical Nav.
- and BS Navs use standard "click" for navigation so it's better, IMO, to not alter that functionality.

The question: Is your menu system fixed, programmatic, or dynamic?

- If it's fixed you can just build this menu system in your html and you will only have to code the interaction.
- If it's programmatic, meaning the nav entries are based on some hierarchical data structure, you will have to loop through the data and build the menu such that the final html conforms to the sample below.
- If it's dynamic, meaning the menu system changes based on some user choice, well that's a whole other beast that I am going to assume is not the case.

This Sample vertical nav based on your post is a fixed menu system.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<ul class="nav flex-sm-column">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Some item</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <div class="btn-group dropright">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Flowers</a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Color</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Smell</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else</a>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <div class="btn-group dropright">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Cars</a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Price</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Engine</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Another Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for reply.
You are right, I am generating the tree structure on the fly.
Imagine a Windows Explorer-like file manager : I need to generate dynamically a tree of folders and files. For Folders I should have a Right-Click menu containing for example "Create new folder" and "Rename folder" and for files I should have "Edit file" and "Delete file". I hope it's clearer now. How do I create SEPARATE menus for each TYPE of node (let's assume 2-3 types for now)

Comment: Menus, context or otherwise, are all basically the same with minor style differences.  It's just a matter of triggering the appropriate menu based on type of click and, in your case, an additional check based on file type (folder vs file).  If you search SO you will find many examples showing how to create context menus with Bootstrap.